# How can set the background of the moda view to be Translucent?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I call my ModalViewController by tapping into a Button. I want this ModalViewController have a  Translucent background like below:

[image]

when i use [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; it gives me a black background:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
    [modalView.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

or if you want to decrease the opacity

```
 [modalView.view setalpha:0.4]; //range is from 0(transparent) to 1(opaque)
```

Comment: it gives a black view in the background when i use this method?

Comment: go to your xib file .and change the topmost view background color to clear color.

Comment: add [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; in the initWithNibName:.... method in your view controller

Comment: change all views background color to clear color. and also other tabs views background color to clear color .. black color is the default background color of every view.. do an NSLog(@" %@ " ,se;f.parentViewController"); so that you can check what is the parent views of modal view

Comment: In the log it gives me (null)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6854/discussion-between-shubhank-and-ziad-tamim)